# JSF 2.0 with Richface 4.0 not rerendering component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Do you have any idea why this part of code isn't working:

View:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="#{labels.comments}" 
    action="#{reservation.displayComments}" 
    render="dataComments" />

<h:panelGroup id="dataComments" rendered="#{reservation.showComments}" >
    ...
<h:panelGroup/>
```

Bean:

```
 public String displayComments(){
    showComments = !showComments;
    return "";
 }
```

Click on the link simply do nothing.

Comment: Your title is different your question. Is it not rendering?or is it not hitting the method.Have you put a break point there to see? any error log you can see in console.Also provide complete bean including showing us how is it getting configured as managed bean. Then atleast full form that surrounds this button. Tallking about form is it in a form at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="#{labels.comments}" 
    action="#{reservation.displayComments}"
    render="dataComments" />

<h:panelGroup id="dataComments">
    <h:panelGroup id="innerPanel" rendered="#{reservation.showComments}" >
        ...
    <h:panelGroup/>
<h:panelGroup/>
```

Always show your dataComments element, unless you will have nothing on the page to refresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks just fine.